# firebase email auth link open in new tab

Tags: firebase, authentication, email-verification

[image]

All users are using the company email client application. Because this application shows the email in the iframe, users need to open the verification link in a new tab/window.

I'd like to customize the firebase email template, but It won't let me do that as shown in the screenshot. Is there really no way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this cannot be achieved. If you want to get creative you can get insight from this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/HTsNAhg2SAE).